# Notepad++ RegEx : Copy search text and replace same by appending value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, notepad++

I've a big text file which contains page numbers (starting from 997 to 2989) after along with its content.

Ex.

```
 997
....
some-content
....

 998
....
some-content
....

 999
....
some-content
....

and so on..
.
.
.
 2989
....
some-content
....
```

I want to append value 1 to every page number mentioned above using regex in notepad++ without affecting its actual content so that it'll display like this:

```
1   997
    ....
    some-content
    ....

1   998
    ....
    some-content
    ....

1   999
    ....
    some-content
    ....

    and so on..
    .
    .
    .
1   2989
    ....
    some-content
    ....
```

By using following regular expression I'm able to find all the page numbers

```
/^(\s|\s\s|\s\s\s)(9|1|2)\d+$/gm
```

But I don't know how can I replace this by appending 1 and keeping same page no as it is.

I've used \1 but its not working and replacing it with blank space.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `^(\s{1,3})([912]\d+)$` and replace with `${1}1 $2` (or `\11 $2`, it is the same)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ohh great its working but one issue its appending blank space before 1. How to avoid that?

Comment: Maybe you need `^(\h{1,3})([912]\d+)$` --> `1$1$2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
^(\h{1,3})([912]\d+)$
```

And replace with `1$1$2`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\h{1,3})`  - Group 1 capturing 1 to 3 horizontal whitespaces
- `([912]\d+)`  - Group 2 capturing the number starting with `9`, `1` or `2` and then having 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of line.

The replacement pattern `1$1$2` contains `1`, then `$1` that is a backreference to the value kept in Group 1 and `$2` referring to the text inside Group 2. With the backreferences, we can re-insert captured subtexts while replacing old text with new one.

[image]